# How Do I Monitor Network Flow with Selenium?

Tags: python, api, selenium-webdriver, networking

I am trying to scrape data from this url with Python-Selenium.
» https://shopee.co.id/PANCI-PRESTO-24cm-3.5L-TEFLON-i.323047288.19137193916?sp_atk=7e8e7abc-834c-4f4a-9234-19da9ddb2445&xptdk=7e8e7abc-834c-4f4a-9234-19da9ddb2445

If you watch the network stream you will see that it returns an api on the back end like this https://shopee.co.id/api/v4/item/get?itemid=19137193916&shopid=323047288. How can I get the response returned by this api with selenium?

Comment: If it is a fixed URL format, why don't you use reqests library instead of Selenium?

Comment: @MahsumAkbas In the Headers, there is a token given only when you open it in the browser. It does not return the data without that token

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```
import json
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

# Set up Selenium webdriver
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
capabilities["goog:loggingPrefs"] = {"performance": "ALL"}
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/brave"
options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities, options=options)

# Navigate to URL and monitor network flow
url = "https://shopee.co.id/PANCI-PRESTO-24cm-3.5L-TEFLON-i.323047288.19137193916?sp_atk=7e8e7abc-834c-4f4a-9234-19da9ddb2445&xptdk=7e8e7abc-834c-4f4a-9234-19da9ddb2445"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)  # Wait for the page to load

# Find any API requests and print the returned data to the screen
logs = driver.get_log("performance")
for entry in logs:
    message = entry.get("message", {})
    parsed_message = json.loads(message)
    message_dict = parsed_message.get("message", {})
    method = message_dict.get("method")
    if method == "Network.requestWillBeSent":
        request = message_dict.get("params", {}).get("request", {})
        url = request.get("url")
        if "https://shopee.co.id/api/v4/item/get?itemid=19137193916&shopid=323047288" in url:
            response_url = url.replace("request", "response")
            response = driver.execute_cdp_cmd(
                "Network.getResponseBody", {"requestId": message_dict.get("params", {}).get("requestId")}
            )
            with open("response.json", "w") as f:
                f.write(response.get("body", ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

I use selenium wire for this. You can do `pip install selenium-wire` to get it and then import it into your project and use it like so:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver 

#Sets the Option to disable response encoding
sw_options = {
    'disable_encoding': True
}
#Creates driver with selected options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(seleniumwire_options=sw_options)

#Starts selenium wire interceptor to monitor network traffic
driver.request_interceptor = interceptor

#Navigate to page
driver.get('https://shopee.co.id/PANCI-PRESTO-24cm-3.5L-TEFLON-i.323047288.19137193916?sp_atk=7e8e7abc-834c-4f4a-9234-19da9ddb2445&xptdk=7e8e7abc-834c-4f4a-9234-19da9ddb2445')

#Iterate through requests and find the one with the endpoint you need in the url
for a in driver.requests:
    if("/api/v4/item/get?itemid=19137193916&shopid=323047288" in a.url):
        body = a.response.body
        print(body)
```

We add `disable encoding` to the options otherwise the body would come back encoded and youd have to decode it manually which can be done like so

```
body = decode(response.body, response.headers.get('Content-Encoding', 'identity'))
```

Or done in the browser options as I did.

You can find more information here:
https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/#response-objects